# Does anyone know how a style title could be adjusted to have custom border and shading?

Tags: microsoft-word

Does anyone know how a style title could be adjusted to look like the following.

What I am trying to achieve:

[image: What I am trying to do]

When I am trying to modify the style through the tab Borders, the different colour stick to the box. However, I am trying to have the box in one colour and the text and the underline in a similar one. The underline should not be at the very end of the border, which is the best I could achieve now.

Welcome to any hints that could help solve the matter. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Borders function will not do what you want ... that is if I understand your question correctly.

Use the Underline feature (Home tab, Font Group) and then only the text will contain the single colored line. You can set the underline color to be the same as the text or different from the text.

Use the Border function to only apply the shading to the paragraph.

Comment: The underline will only be under the actual words, though; it won't extend beyond them to the right as shown in the illustration. You'd have to, e.g., add a right tab stop and apply underlining to that too.

Comment: It is indeed working with the tab. However, I would like to extend the coloured surface around the text and what is underline.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, which expands on Rich Michaels's answer and my comment to it:

1. Either in the **Styles** pane on the side of the window or in the **Styles** gallery on the **Home** tab of the ribbon, right-click the style that's being used for the heading, and then click **Modify**.
2. In the **Modify Style** dialog box, on the **Format** drop-down in the lower-left corner, select **Border**.
3. On the **Shading** tab, set the shading color.
4. As you've seen, adding shading won't give you the extra 'padding' that you want around the text. Therefore, on the **Borders** tab, add borders in the same color that you used for the shading. You can adjust the thickness of the border, and even set a different border thickness on each side, to get the look that you want.

   Because the borders are available in only a limited number of predefined thicknesses, you can fine-tune the result by clicking **Options**, and then setting the **Top**, **Bottom**, **Left**, and **Right** fields to get exactly what you want. For example, if you want your shaded box to extend 9 points above and below the text, but 6 points on the left and right, add a 6-point border to all sides, and then, in the **Border and Shading Options** dialog box, set **Top** and **Bottom** to **3 pt**, and **Left** and **Right** to **0 pt**.
5. Back in the **Modify Style** dialog box, select **Format** > **Paragraph**. Then click **Tabs**, and set a right tab at the right text margin.
6. Back in the **Modify Style** dialog box, select **Format** > **Font**, and then set the desired underline style and color.
7. After the last character of your heading text, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> before you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In the following example, I've modified the built-in Heading 1 style in this manner.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. The only downside with this solution, is that it requires the insertion of a tab to have the underline going all the way. I am making a template for my company design and I guess it will be unhandy if for each title, it will be required to put a tab

Comment: @user4926345: Yes, that is the main downside to this solution. But what you're trying to do isn't really supported in Word and requires workarounds. Some people like to use tables for such things, though there are several serious downsides to that approach too. Because this is for a company  template and you don't want to burden the people who will use it, you may ultimately have to settle for either the underline or the shading, and give up on including both. And actually, from a design standpoint, it's probably better to use just one.